# Оформление песен с прямой речью нескольких героев

Tags: оформление-текста

Как правильно эту песенку оформить? Я просто не понимаю, как правильно песни оформлять, когда есть речи двух персонажей. Может, даже так неправильно? Дайте знать, как правильно.

> «Здесь пенни, там шиллинг, а где-нибудь фунт». — «Большие деньги». / «Стал Бобби мошенник, мошенник и плут». — «Почему мошенник и плут?» / «Скопил целый бут». — «А-а-а, молодец…».

Comment: Дайте знать, как правильно? Вы думаете, есть специальные правила? Почему вы так думаете? Если вам лично нужно решить  эту проблему, начните ее решать сами. Сравнивайте, делайте выводы, приведите ваши размышления.. Репутация 5К позволяет это сделать. Почему вы постоянно ждете помощи?   Вам помогут, если вы сами сделаете хотя бы что-то.

Comment: МИНИАТЮРА. Что-то мне совсем скучно стало. До ближайшего города сорок верст.  Дождь, грязь, слякоть, ветер… Ну что вот делать целый вечер? Эй, приказчик, ты вот что,  Найди-ка мне, как правильно  песенку оформить? Я просто не понимаю, как правильно песни оформлять, когда есть речи двух персонажей. -  Да зачем вам это, барин! - А я знаю зачем! Захотелось вот!  А ты уж найди, голубчик, уважь. Или прикажи кому найти. - Да я сейчас, как изволите-с..

Comment: https://avtoram.com/dialogi_vszenariyah/ - Диалоги в сценариях

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавлю в тему **пример оформления песни с диалогом.** В каждом конкретном случае предлагается то решение, которое соответствует авторской художественной задаче. Другими словами, нужно изобразить ситуацию максимально наглядно, создать нужный **художественный образ**.

**Иосиф Уткин — Типичный случай.**

```
 Двое тихо говорили,
 Расставались и корили:
 «Ты такая…»
 «Ты такой!..»
 «Ты плохая…»
 «Ты плохой!..»
 «Уезжаю в Лениград… Как я рада!»
 «Как я рад!!!»

 Дело было на вокзале,
 Дело было этим летом,
 Все решили. Все сказали.
 Были куплены билеты.

 Паровоз в дыму по пояс
 Бил копытом на пути:
 Голубой курьерский поезд
 Вот-вот думал отойти.
«Уезжаю в Лениград… Как я рада!»
«Как я рад!!!»

 Но когда…
 Чудак в фуражке,
 Поднял маленький флажок,
 Паровоз пустил барашки,
 Семафор огонь зажег…

 Но когда…
 Двенадцать двадцать
 Бьет звонок. Один. Другой.
 Надо было расставаться…
 «До-ро-гая!»
 «До-ро-гой…»
 «Я такая!»
 «Я такой!»
 «Я плохая!»
 «Я плохой!»
 «Я не еду в Ленинград… Как я рада!»
  «Как я рад!!!»
```

Поискала подходящее **исполнение** песни, но мне ничего решительно не нравилось. Какое-то невыразительное бормотание! Но потом остановилась на юмористическом варианте. **Классно** все изобразили!

https://salda.ws/video.php?id=NpkuWikWa2I

Answer (score 3):

Эта тема вряд ли относится напрямую к орфографии, потому что это [сценарий и его запись](https://snegiri-studio.ru/scenarij-filma-teksty-scenariev-filmov-i-serialov-skachat).

Вот как пример, скажем, сценария фильма Брат:

> Данила молча смотрел на него. К нему бежали два здоровых охранника в штатском. Данила оглянулся.
> — Фамилия? — монотонно спросил уже немолодой капитан с одутловатым испитым лицом.
> — Багров, — с трудом произнес Данила опухшими губами.
> — Имя, отчество. — Капитан поднял глаза на избитое лицо. — Данила Сергеевич, 75 г. р., Вокзальная, 22. —  Место работы.
> — Дембель не отгулял еще. — Данила отвечал беззлобно, выдерживая небольшие паузы.

Или вот сценарий ["Мы из будущего"](https://snegiri-studio.ru/pl/fileservice/user/file/download/h/8c3544de0572f6dfef1ef2624c47261e.pdf) - как видно, оформление текста зависит от выбора оформления сценариста и его видения. Каких-то строгих правил оформления скорее всего нет, главное, чтобы было понятно, ну и грамотно.

Или вот сценарий [Сутеева, чё-то про Мишку](https://sheba.spb.ru/bib/multfilm-fs3-1955.htm)(оно правда само как-то оформляется=), поэтому я кусок оставлю одним с оформлением, а остальное с другим):

> — Эх! Надо было слона ему дать! — с досадой говорит Вова, срывает с головы свою кепку и сердито бросает её на землю.
> А дома шёл урок русского языка.
> Таня разучивала стихи с куклой Зоечкой:

```
  Одеяло убежало,
  Улетела простыня.
  И подушка, как лягушка,
  Ускакала от меня.
 
  Неожиданно в комнату вошёл мрачный Вова с «Кометой» в руках и молча бросил модель в угол комнаты.
```

...

```
  Это очень хорошо,
  Это просто хорошо,
  Это страшно хорошо,
  Замечательно!
 
  За окном постучали.
  — Замечательно! — сказал Вова и... проснулся. Послышался шёпот:
```

**То есть, оформляется максимально просто: описываешь, что должен показывать, говорить, играть сначала состав съемочной группы и актёры, а потом - видеть, слышать и понимать и зритель.**

Но твоя проблема, что ты не можешь определить цель или задачу, которой тебе нужно следовать руководствуясь той или иной грамматической форме, если вообще таковая форма имеется.

Какой-то формы может и не быть, мысль не подчинена форме, наоборот, форма является проявлением мысли. Главное, чтобы было понятно, это как Ивлев говорит: когда вкусно, тогда вкусно.

**Когда понятно, тогда понятно -** ты же пишешь часто нарочито непонятно.

Ну и смысл пихать такое количество "ёлок" в текст, это же лишние символы, зачем, притом что это песня и диалог?

Непонятно, для кого оформляется данный текст, это пересказ или что, какая стилистика? Или ты хочешь свои писать вещи?

Без ответа на подобные вопрос невозможно определить форму того, как это должно выглядеть, а если ты можешь ответить на эти вопросы, то скорее всего ты и форму знаешь, ты же как-то пишешь свой бред, то есть для тебя это всё имеет смысл?

А для нас - не всегда)

Так поделись, пожалуйста, какой смысл в твоих царапках или это графоманский рефлекс?

А, ну и вот, кстати, определение задачи сразу дает ответ на твой почти-вопрос: сценарий мультфильма "Остров сокровищ". Точнее это не сценарий, а [либретто](http://lib.ru/KSP/ostrowso.txt) - песенная партия.

> Композитор    В.Быстряков
> Либретто. Н.Олев
> А.Балагин

> **Трагическая и поучительная история о**

```
    мальчике Бобби, который любил деньги.
```

> С рождения Бобби пай-мальчиком был, (Молодец...)
> Имел Бобби хобби - он деньги любил, (Хороший мальчик...)
> Любил и копил. (Что было дальше?)

> Все дети как дети - живут без забот, (Счастливое детство...)
> А Боб на диете - не ест и не пьет, (Бедненький мальчик...)
> В копилку кладет

> Деньги-деньги, дребеденьги,
> Позабыв покой и лень.
> Делай деньги, делай деньги,
> А остальное все дребедень,
> А остальное все дребедебень.
> (Дальше что было?)

Ну и тд.